# Maximize point in plane value

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, plane

So, basically, I need a way to figure out what is the point in plane with the maximum value that has coordinates strictly less than a point.

One way to do it would be by checking all the points which has the complexity .

```
O(N) time, N being the number of points.
O(1) space.
```

Another way would be to do it with a binary indexed tree (BIT) which would give the complexity

```
O(log(max(X))*log(max(Y)) time, X being the maximum x coordinate and Y being the max y coordinate.
O(max(X)*max(Y)) space, this is the main problem, I can't afford that much space.
```

I would like something that has logarithmic complexity and as close as possible to O(N) space.

Example:

[image: Example]

Best values for each points are:

```
A -> 0 ( none )
B -> 2 ( A )
C -> 2 ( A )
D -> 0 ( none )
E -> 10 ( D )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm with O(N log N) construction time (O(N) if you're ambitious and implement one of the fancy data structures) and space and O(log N) time queries.

The idea is to take an incremental solution to the 1D problem with O(log N) time insertions and make the central data structure (a balanced binary search tree) [partially persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) using standard techniques described on the linked Wikipedia page. To build the 2D data structure, sort the points by x increasing and then insert them in order into the 1D structure, saving references to the 1D snapshots in a list sorted by x. To query the 2D structure, binary search for the last snapshot before we inserted a point with point.x ≥ query.x, then do a 1D query.

To solve the 1D problem on the y-axis, we keep the *non-dominated* points in a balanced binary search tree. (A point is dominated if there is another point with lesser y and greater value.) To query, find the predecessor of query.y in the tree. To insert, first query y to make sure that the new point isn't dominated. If it's non-dominated, then insert it and delete points after it that it dominates. The amortized insertion time is O(log N).

Comment: Uhm, I almost understand your solution but I can't really figure out how to combine the x and y solution to the 2D one.

So, basically, you're querying for the point strictly above the target with the highest value and then you're finding the predecessor on the y axis of that point such that the predecessor is dominant?

If so, how do you know that the y of that element has a y value strictly less than the target?

Comment: @RazvanD For each point from left to right, we insert that point into a tree sorted top to bottom (discarding dominated points). After each point, we snapshot the tree. We ensure that the x-coordinate of the possible result points is less by choosing the version of the tree that has only those points. We ensure that the y-coordinate is less by choosing the predecessor of the query's y-coordinate in the snapshot.